# I'm having an issue with running my app on the Android emulator

Tags: android

Im having a problem with the android studio emulator. everytime I hit run theres a message pop.
The application could not be installed: SKIPPED_INSTALL Failure to kill com.smstechnology.diceroller Retry.
Here's the mainActivity.kt

```
package com.smstechnology.diceroller

import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity

/**
 * This activity allows the user to roll a dice and view the result
 * on the screen.
 */
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val rollButton: Button = findViewById(R.id.bottom)
        rollButton.setOnClickListener {
            rollDice()
        }
    }
    /**
     * Roll the dice and update the screen with the result.
     */
    private fun rollDice() {
        // Create new Dice object with 6 sides and roll it
        val dice = Dice(6)
        val diceRoll = dice.roll()
        // Update the screen with the dice roll
        val resultTextView: TextView = findViewById(R.id.textView)
        resultTextView.text = diceRoll.toString()
    }
}

class Dice(private val numSides: Int) {

    fun roll(): Int {
        return (1..numSides).random()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

These install failures seem to have all kinds of solutions - hopefully someone knows what that specific message means!

Personally I'd try killing the app from within Android Studio, using the red stop button. If that doesn't work, try going into the app's settings on the emulator (you can long press on its icon on the task switcher) and do a Force Stop

Some people had some success disabling Instant Run, but I can't see options for that anymore

For me, what's always caused it is the virtual device not having enough storage - if I bumped it up 1GB or so, things would install fine. It wasn't a very helpful message!

Comment: Thank you cactustictacs!